# Java - truncate string from left with formatter flag

Tags: java, string-formatting

I have a string, say:

```
String s = "0123456789";
```

I want to pad it with a formatter. I can do this two ways:

```
String.format("[%1$15s]", s); //returns [     0123456789]
```

or

```
String.format("[%1$-15s]", s); // returns [0123456789     ]
```

if I want to truncate text I do

```
String.format("[%1$.5s]", s);  // returns [01234]
```

if I want to truncate from the left, I thought I could do this:

```
String.format("[%1$-.5s]", s); // throws MissingFormatWidthException
```

but this failed, so I tried this:

```
String.format("[%1$-0.5s]", s); // throws MissingFormatWidthException
```

as well as this:

```
String.format("[%1$.-5s]", s); // throws UnknownFormatConversionException
```

So how then do I truncate from the left using a format flag?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `-` flag is for justification and doesn't seem to have anything to do with truncation.

The `.` is used for "precision", which apparently translates to truncation for string arguments.

I don't think format strings supports truncating from the left. You'll have to resort to

```
String.format("[%.5s]", s.length() > 5 ? s.substring(s.length()-5) : s);
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured. The reason I didnt want to resort to this, is that I have constructed a sorta wrapper for the string format, which allows users to provide a value Map<String, Object> and to reference entities in it by name instead of index (IE "%SOMEKEY$s", instead of "%1$s"). It needs to be able to truncate from the left. This just funnels in the values into the standard string formatter. I found a work around with some moderately cleaver string reversals, and regex though, so all's well that ends well :D

Comment: Sounds like a neat utility. Have you looked into [`MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html)? Doesn't seem to do what you want, but perhaps it's closer than `String.format`.

Answer (score 11):

I hope this is what you need:

```
System.out.println("'" + String.format("%-5.5s", "") + "'");
System.out.println("'" + String.format("%-5.5s", "123") + "'");
System.out.println("'" + String.format("%-5.5s", "12345") + "'");
System.out.println("'" + String.format("%-5.5s", "1234567890.....") + "'");
```

output length is always 5:

**'     '** - *filled with 5 spaces*
**'123  '** *filled with 2 spaces after* 
**'12345'** - *equals*
**'12345'** - *truncated*

in addition:

```
System.out.println("'" + String.format("%5.5s", "123") + "'");
```

output:

**'  123'** *filled with 2 spaces before*

Comment: This answer is correct as far as truncating the right part of the string, but the OP wants to truncate from the left (unusual but that's what he wants)

Answer (score -1):

You could also use method for manipulating Strings

```
substring(startindex, endIndex)
```

Returns a string object that starts a the specified index an goes to, but doesn't include, the end index.

And also could try to use StringBuilder class.

Comment: The question is specifically asking how to do it with Formatter flags.

Comment: apache commons StringUtils.substring(...) seems to work well for me (since I already have the library in use).

Comment: @VGR, sometimes the best answers are the ones that suggest a better way of doing things than what someone originally hoped for.  It is by no means a bad answer, especially considering the accepted answer said "you can't with string.format" and suggests a workaround itself (ironically, using a *substring method*).